# How does the iPhone know it's not using an Apple cable?

Tags: iphone, power

Sometimes when I plug a cable in to charge, the iPhone says it may not work with this device. How does it know it's not an Apple cable?

Comment: Just let you know it is not reliable. Using official cable would show up this prompt ocassionally.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Apple has a program called [MFi](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/) and detects if the cable has a certified chip inside. The chip just says that it's been officially 'Made For iOS.'

Comment: I don't know about that.. Can you provide some kind of evidence or documentation on this Apple "certified chip"?

Comment: @tjt263, this post goes into detail about the chip’s internals: http://blog.freedelity.be/blogs_message-49-1-Hacking_the_Lighning_cable__let_s_talk_tech.html

Answer (score 0):

@ https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204566

This helps clear up some confusion on the topic

Apple recommends using only accessories that Apple has certified and that come with the MFi badge. Learn about the issues that counterfeit or uncertified Lightning accessories can cause and how to identify these accessories.

Comment: Link-only answers tend to be downvoted and eventually deleted because links can and will expire. Although many Apple Support documents still exist well after their 'expiration date' it is best to brazenly copy/paste the essential parts of this page into your answer to provide help without having to visit the Support page. I myself have several accepted answers using information gleaned from Support pages, but I have properly attributed the source.

Comment: Thank you for the information. New to this, and tend to a lot of times have very useful information on topics or in this case at least have researched enough to know that the answer is already out there and often times much more clearly put together than I can answer.